# Can the following sentence be interpreted in two different ways?

Tags: meaning

> Ich hatte gehofft, Frauen würden sie anders behandeln.

1. {*sie* as the subject}: I had hoped they would treat women in a different manner.
2. {*Frauen* as the subject}: I had hoped women would treat her/them in a different manner.

---

If both are indeed possible, do different intonations or something help to distinguish between the two meanings? Or does the sentence leave some ambiguity in any case?

Comment: Depends on the context, as so often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence can be interpreted in many different ways.

The written version, as posted in your question, can not only be interpreted in two ways, but in four different ways (numbers 1 to 4 in the list below).

If this sentence would not be written, but spoken, you even have four additional possibilities, because then you don't know if it was »sie« (she, her, they, them) or »Sie« (you<sub>*singular*</sub>, you<sub>*plural*</sub>). (#5 - #8).

You can eliminate the hope-part, and condense the sentence to its relevant part:

> Frauen behandeln sie/Sie anders.

---

And here is the list of all eight possible interpretations:

1. *Frauen* = subject (in nominative case); *sie* = lower case;  accusative object, 3rd person singular.

   > Women treat her different.
2. same as 1, but *sie* is 3rd person plural

   > Women treat them different.
3. *Frauen* = accusative object, *sie* = subject in nominative case, 3rd person singular

   > She treats women different.
4. Like 3, but *sie* = 3rd person plural

   > They treat women different.
5. *Frauen* = subject; *Sie* is uppercase, 2nd person singular

   > Women treat you<sub>*singular*</sub> different.
6. *Frauen* = subject; *Sie* is uppercase, 2nd person plural

   > Women treat you<sub>*plural*</sub> different.

   (As you see, here also is an ambiguity in English; you don't know if *you* is singular or plural)
7. *Frauen* = accusative object, *Sie* is uppercase, 2nd person singular

   > You<sub>*singular*</sub> treat women different.
8. *Frauen* = accusative object, *Sie* is uppercase, 2nd person plural

   > You<sub>*plural*</sub> treat women different.

   (Same singular-plural-ambiguity between 7 and 8 as between 5 and 6)

---

Only context can help you to distinguish between those possibilities. Intonation can be misinterpreted, so it doesn't help very much.

Comment: "I had hoped **they** would treat **women** in a different manner." Danke. So if you have this specific meaning in mind, how would you construct the sentence without causing ambiguity?

Comment: *Ich hatte gehofft, Frauen würden **von ihr/von Ihnen** anders behandelt.* *Ich hatte gehofft, **von/durch Frauen** würde sie/würden sie/würden Sie anders behandelt.*

Comment: The best way is to build a sentence in passive voice: "I had hoped women would have been treated by them in a different manner." = "Ich hatte gehofft, Frauen würden von ihnen anders behandelt werden."

Comment: Die Mehrdeutigkeit von sie/Sie ist gar nicht Thema.

Comment: @userunknown: Diese Mehrdeutigkeit besteht aber, und da das Thema der Frage Mehrdeutigkeit ist, wäre es falsch, diese Mehrdeutigkeit zu verschweigen, nur weil der OP sie gerade nicht im Sinn hatte als er die Frage stellte.

Comment: They und her/them zerstreuen in der Frage den Verdacht, der Satz könne in diesem Sinne mehrdeutig sein. Die Diskussion solcher Abseitigkeiten macht das Posting zu einem Zeitloch, in dem man eine möglicherweise existierende Antwort auf das, was gefragt war, erst suchen muss.

Answer (score -1):

> Ich hatte gehofft, Frauen würden sie anders behandeln.

Is indeed ambiguous.

Better would be:

> Ich hatte gehofft, sie würden Frauen anders behandeln.

bzw.

> Ich hatte gehofft, Frauen würden sie anders behandeln.

Comment: Moving the words around does not resolve the ambiguity at all. It is still ambiguous in your re-ordered sentences.

Comment: Satz 3 sieht auch nicht viel anders aus, als Satz 1.